# Can "stuck" be used with a continuous form?

Tags: continuous

Can I use "stuck" with a continuous form? In other words, shall I say about a parcel that has not arrived:

> Hope it is not being **stuck** in the Christmas post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, one would not typically use "stuck" in a continuous construction. Your example should be:

> I hope it is not stuck in the Christmas post.

The only common continuous constructions are for referring to the state change from stuck to unstuck, such as "becoming stuck" or "getting stuck", or for referring to repeating events, such as "being stuck in traffic every day". However, when referring to a single occurrence, the continuous should no longer be used once the state has changed.

Similarly, one would only say "something is being destroyed" while the destruction is happening. Afterwards, you would say "it is destroyed."

Comment: why can we say "he is being silly" and not "it is being stuck", as both won't last forever?

Comment: @user5577 Because "being stuck" only refers to the single point in time when something becomes stuck, e.g. stops moving. Once the motion has stopped, the the thing is no longer *becoming* stuck, it *is* stuck.

Comment: @Tashus - Agreed. It is interesting, though, how we can say, "I hope it is not being **held** in the Christmas post."

Comment: @J.R. The difference is that holding something is a continuous action, whereas sticking is a process that must complete before the object's state has changed. Similarly we would only say "someone is being killed" at the time of their death.

Comment: even if the "sticking" won't last it is a not a definitive  but a temporary state  that is why I thought we could use the continuous

Comment: @user5577 That is a reasonable thought, but it is not the case here. "Sticking" describes the *process* rather than the state. The state is simply "stuck".

Comment: Consider *I haven't put up bedroom curtains in my new house yet. I hope I'm not **being watched** by the neighbours when I get dressed every morning*. In principle, ***being*** isn't syntactically *necessary* there, but it would almost always be included.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That use involves a repeating event. I'll add a note with similar use of "being stuck".

Comment: @Tashus: Nicely explained! How about *Normally the Postal Service respects its users' privacy, but because we've had some high-profile "terrorist letter bomb" incidents lately, suspicious packets were [being] opened over the Christmas period*. I find I'm inclined to interpret the "non-continuous" version as implying ***all** suspicious packages*, whereas the continuous participle version seems to imply ***some** suspicious packages*. Perhaps somehow related to the idea that one focuses on the *activity* (of "opening"), but the other focuses on the *experience* (of "being opened").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! Hmm. I see what you mean about the implication, but I can't think of a concrete way to explain it as a rule. It seems related to me, but I can't quite put my finger on it.